# Unsafe redirect when running Ruby On Rails app (with Devise and SAML )on localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, saml

I have a Ruby On Rails app (Ruby 3.1, Rails 7.0.1) using Devise and the devise_saml_authenticatable gem as I authenticate against Microsoft Azure Active Directory.

After upgrading my app from Ruby 2.7.4 and Rails 6.1.x I get the following error:

```
ActionController::Redirecting::UnsafeRedirectError in Devise::SamlSessionsController#new

Unsafe redirect to "https://login.microsoftonline.com/ba06cbf3-c661-4896-8dbc- 
cd190052c299/saml2?SAMLRequest=fVJNa9ww...", pass allow_other_host: true to redirect anyway.
```

This error only occurs if I run my app locally (with HTTPS):

```
bundle exec rails s -e development -b "ssl://0.0.0.0:3000?key=./config/ssl/localhost.key&cert=./config/ssl/localhost.crt"
```

but the error does not occur when I run the app on my server.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved, bundle  update today provided GEM updates to devise_saml_authenticable (v1.8.0) and now the error disappeared.